# Filter values from elements inside list

Tags: r

I have list of sentences like this `mydf <- data.frame(a=c("hihih ojkm hi how","I am fine yuuu dude hwz yo"))` where I want to find every word in that sentence is a english word. To know whether each word in a sentence is a english word I am using this code. `strs <- strsplit(c("hihih ojkm hi how")," ")
df <- lapply(strs, is.word)`
which gives the result

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Now I want to filter the sentence to extract English words alone like result: "hi how" .Moreover I want to traverse through every sentence and every word to check whether it is an English word and display the list of proper sentence as result. I am complete novice. Any guidance would be much helpful

Comment: Try `paste(strs[[1]]df[[1]], collapse = ' ')`

Comment: Where does `is.word` come from? What package? When you use a non-base R package you should include `library(pckname)` as the first instruction of your example script.

Comment: is.word is from qdapDictionaries package, and yes I have included before I executed this code

Comment: @Sotos Yes thats an option but I have to do this for n sentence and m words inside it. Should I use a list or list of list. If yes, how do I apply that function ?

Comment: You will have to use `sapply` to iterate. I don't have that package installed at the moment

Comment: using sapply I should read the sentence, and using lapply I should check the word. Is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
wordsonly <- function(chars){
    wordchunks <- strsplit(chars," ")#Big assumption that all words are separated by one space.
    wordtest <- lapply(wordchunks,is.word)
    return(wordchunks[[1]][wordtest[[1]]])
}

mydf <- data.frame(a=c("hihih ojkm hi how","I am fine yuuu dude hwz yo"))
mydf$a <- as.character(mydf$a) #just making sure these are strings not factors
mydf$wordsonly <- lapply(mydf$a,wordsonly) #note that each entry in $wordsonly is a list
```

Comment: Wow! This is perfect. I was struggling for this. Thanks a lot Steve.